# Changing default dialer tones

Tags: android

I am creating an android app in which I am trying to modify the default dialer keyboard tones (1,2,3....) (NOT the incoming caller tunes etc) 
This is my first approach for such kind of android app.

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this? 
I read it somewhere that "ToneGenerator" class can be used to achieve what I've in mind but not sure how to use this class.

A little help here will be highly appreciated.

Thnx..

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to generate tone.

```
ToneGenerator generator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,100);
generator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0);
Thread.sleep(500);
generator.stopTone();
generator.release();
```

Change TONE_DTMF_0 according to your needs

Comment: Thanks mandeesh for the Head start. I believe to do this first I need to idetify which key user has clicked and then change the tone at runtime or do I have ability to change the key tones at the system level as well ?

Comment: you cant change another apps behaviour

Comment: So the best possible solutions is to check which dialer key user has clicked and then change the tone of that key at runtime. right ? Nandeesh can you guide a little how this might I get which key is pressed info? If not code, any weblink will be a great help too.

Comment: if you are trying to change the sound when numbers are pressed in dialer app, that is not possible

Comment: Ohh..that's what I'm trying to do :(. But one can create their own custom dialer app that can override the default one..right ?